# Why does firefox ask me to upgrade Flash?

Tags: firefox, flash, updates, firefox-3.6

Why does Firefox ask me to upgrade flash occasionally when there appears to be no difference between the versions (10.1 r86 to 10.1 r86)?  Also why do I have to always re-download the Adobe download manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/plugincheck/ say?
For me (Firefox 3.6.9) it's reporting that I have `10.1.82.76` installed and am up-to-date.

**Important Note** you *can* get Flash player for Firefox (and other non-IE browsers) *without* the download manager - you just have to dig around in their tech support area until you find the [Manual Installer](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/191/tn_19166.html#main_ManualInstaller).

## Recommendation:

1. Uninstall Flash
2. Reinstall using the [manual installer](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/191/tn_19166.html#main_ManualInstaller)
3. Check the [Mozilla plugin check page](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/plugincheck/) to make sure it's worked